# How to use boost asio's built-in coroutine ts support?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

Using g ++ - 10 I try to compile the example of working with coroutines presented in the documentation, but the compiler does not see the classes associated with coroutine ts, although they are in the header file. Boost version - 1.75

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include "boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp"
    #include "boost/asio/awaitable.hpp"
    #include "boost/asio/coroutine.hpp"
    
    boost::asio::awaitable<void> echo(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            char data[1024];
            for (;;)
            {
                std::size_t n = co_await socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), boost::asio::use_awaitable);
                co_await async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(data, n), boost::asio::use_awaitable);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::printf("echo Exception: %s\n", e.what());
        }
    }
```

cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(asio_ineer_coro_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -pthread -fcoroutines")
find_package(Boost 1.75.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(asio_ineer_coro_test main.cpp)
```

Comment: Compiled fine [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/156da450f445574e) with `-std=c++2a` compiler flag.

Comment: @rafix07, my flags  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -pthread -fcoroutines")